# How to connect DAC - MCP4725 to the speaker?

Tags: audio, dac

I don't have any experience in hardware.
I am writing a simple program in Raspberry pi to write
audio samples to the DAC MCP4725. Next, I want to connect to
the small speaker. What should be the rating of the speaker?
I need a simple circuit to do so. Like, I checked that I need to
connect the ouput of MCP4725 to a capacitor to get a pure AC signal.
Next, I need to amplfiy this to drive a small speaker. I am planning to
connect this to 3W minimum speaker 4 ohms or 8 ohms. What are the things
I need to check in the datasheet of MCP4725 in order to drive the audio?

Here is the datasheet -

https://docs.rs-online.com/18f7/A700000006619099.pdf

Answer (score 0):

to achieve 3 watts (RMS is how Vrms * Vrms / speaker_impedance. we find

Power * Speaker_impedance = Vrms * Vrms = 12

Vrms = sqrt(12) or 3.5 volts rms or about 5 volts peakpeak.

Thus you need +- 5 volts at a minimum, or 5 volts with a H-bridge power output amplifier.

Comment: how do did you arrive from 3.5 volt rms to peak voltage?

Comment: What should be the circuitry ?